# Wait for animation function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, samsung-smart-tv

I have the following methods in javascript:

```
Controller.prototype.changeScene = function (curScene, newScene) {
    sf.scene.hide(curScene);
    sf.scene.show(newScene, curScene);
    sf.scene.focus(newScene);
};
```

And in another JS Class:

```
Test.prototype.handleHide = function () {
    alert("SceneDialog.handleHide()");
    $(".screenOverlay").fadeOut("slow");
    $(".dialogBox").fadeOut("slow");
};
```

`sf.scene.hide()` calls the `handleHide` method. In `handleHide` there's some animation, but it's not shown. The Controller doesn't wait for it to be finished.

I tried `$.when(sf.scene.hide()).done()` without any luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: which animation functions are you using? `animate`? `fadeout` and `fadein` have callback functions for when they are complete

Comment: Which animations are you waiting on to finish? As written, both fadeOut's will execute, and immediately return to the next statement.

Comment: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup

Comment: `webkitTransitionEnd` `oTransitionEnd` `otransitionend` `transitionend` `msTransitionEnd` events don't help here?

Comment: CSS Transitions don't work, sf.scene.show() overlays the current scene with a complete new markup and css.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the jQuery [queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) to keep a list of animations that are queued to occur only after the previous one has completed.

```
sf.scene.hide(curScene);
sf.scene.show(newScene, curScene);
sf.scene.focus(newScene);
```

would become:

```
sf.scene.hide(curScene);
sf.scene.queue(function() {
    $(this).show(newScene, curScene);
    $(this).dequeue();
});
sf.scene.queue(function() {
    sf.scene.focus(newScene);
    $(this).dequeue();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) function of jquery to call a callback when ALL animations are over.

Try out:

```
Test.prototype.handleHide = function (callback) {
    $(".screenOverlay,.dialogBox").each(
        function(i) {
            $( this ).fadeOut("slow");
        }
    );
    $(".screenOverlay,.dialogBox").promise().done(callback);
};
```

And pass the callback as an argument to handleHide. Your changeScene function should look like this:

```
Controller.prototype.changeScene = function (curScene, newScene) {
    sf.scene.hide(curScene, function() {
        sf.scene.show(newScene, curScene);
        sf.scene.focus(newScene);
    });
};
```

Comment: Will this invoke the callback 2x, or wait till both fade animations to complete and invoke the callback once?

Comment: That was a good question. Here's jquery doc statement: "If multiple elements are animated, it is important to note that the callback is executed once per matched element, not once for the animation as a whole.". You're right, callback will be executed twice.

Comment: It seems that the promise() method was made for that purpose: http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I get the following error when hide is called: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(".screenOverlay,.dialogBox").fadeOut("slow").promise()'). I'm trying to solve it :)

Comment: Try processing the $('.screenOverlay, .dialogBox") classes using .each() method like in the example here: http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Answer (score 1):

if you are using jquery animation functions, jquery generally provides a `complete` parameter which will be called when the function is complete.

using [`fadeout`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/):

```
$('#test').fadeOut('slow', function() {
  // fadeout is finished!! do something
});
```